# jQuery position element from the mouse point (and more)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm writing a jQuery plugin for adding context menus to elements.
Now, I need to fix the position of the context menu. If there is not enough space to show the entire context menu from the mouse bottom, then it should show from the mouse top.
I tried some things but not works like I want.

Here is the code on jsFinddle: http://jsfiddle.net/evandroprogram/pRPQq/

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go mate, I've forked and updated your fiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/joevallender/j5Vy9/

The code change is this

```
var screenBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
var menuHeight = _contextMenu.height();
var menuBottom = menuHeight + options.positionY;
if(menuBottom > screenBottom) {
    _contextMenu.css({
        top: "-=" + menuHeight
    })
}
```

Placed just after you set _contextMenu.css()

**EDIT** Just tested again and that isn't pixel perfect but it does work and should give you a decent clue if you want to tweak it :)

Comment: For perfect align just replace `_contextMenu.height()` by `_contextMenu.outerHeight()` Thank you.

Comment: +1 good call! `outerHeight()` is of course the best thing to be using